# How do the professionals in the adult industry avoid contracting STDs?

Tags: adult-movies

With actors and actresses in multiple movies with multiple partners; what measures does the industry take in order to prevent their workers from contracting these diseases?

Comment: Fair warning: Inappropriate comments or answers will be deleted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Up until recently, this was all managed by the [Adult Industry Medical Health Care Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adult_Industry_Medical_Health_Care_Foundation).  Every performer was required to go through a complete suite of tests every 30 days.  Under federal and state regulations, condoms are mandatory.

However, producers don't like to use them and no one is enforcing their use regularly, but the testing is mandatory and performers must bring an affidavit of their health to shoots

According to a few blog posts, "Talent Testing" is the new company that is helping manage the testing and certifying the health of the performers.

Answer (score 3):

Condoms, required tests before hand, regularly scheduled required tests.